# ajax show/hide script that alternates between showing two divs

Tags: jquery, ajax, show-hide

Could someone please tell me how to make an ajax hide/show toggle script also alternate between showing the contents of another element block. For example I have this iframe (that is hidden on the page):

```
<iframe class="slidingframe" id="thisframe" name="search" src="content.html"></iframe>
```

And the hide/show state of that iframe is controlled by this form button:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="fsearch" action="./Affiliates/search_db/search.php" method="get" target="search">
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="send-button" />
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="1" />
<label for="sitesearch">
<input id="sitesearch" class="tfield" type="text" name="query" size="30" />
</label>
</form>
```

Now what I want is when I click the button it should show the iframe I specified while also hiding this one:

```
<div id="my_div">some content here</div>
```

And also once I click outside of the area of the first iframe or anything outside of it I would like for it to go back to being hidden and leaving only the second div I specified (myDiv) which is very important because all of the contents is loaded into this div. While the form button when clicked fires a site search and load the data in the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/hetsE/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.show_hide').click(function() {
        if ($('#div_one').is(':visible')) {
            $('#div_one').hide(2000);
            $('#div_two').show(2000);
        }
        else {
            $('#div_one').show(2000);
            $('#div_two').hide(2000);
        }    
    });
});​
```

Comment: I saw it after I posted the question and changed it.

Comment: Yeah and it seems to work fine there. Is it okay if I updated my question and then have you take a look at it then.

Comment: it works on the demo but now that I've updated the question what I am trying to accomplish is possible right?

Comment: I think its possible you understand the demo and apply it to your code

Comment: Thanks very much for your assistance Adil. So that's one part of the problem out of the way. Now all I want is for the iframe to disappear when I click outside of it, whether it be on a link or just a blank area, and for the default content that was there first to reappear.

Comment: You may make a new question for that, it will be help me to understand what exactly you need